# What is causing white stains on scanned negative? Is there a way to fix this?

Tags: film, scanning, storage, negative-film, scratches

I'm scanning some of my negatives, and here I find a whole roll covered with these kind of marks all over. The film has been develop in a processor. The images were stored for a while. I don't remember how they where when they came out of development. I tried sipping them with an anti-static cloth but it feels like I need a lot of pressure to start attenuating them. In that process I'm afraid to ver scratch the negative.

[image]

[image]

I wonder if this happened during development or maybe storage?
Is there a way to get rid of those?

Comment: Are these spots on the _physical_ negatives or just on the scans?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are there little white dots on my bw negative, and how can I fix it?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/100849/why-are-there-little-white-dots-on-my-bw-negative-and-how-can-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like some crazy dust to me.

See this question for some general cleaning advice: [How to clean 35mm negative film?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/37360/how-to-clean-35mm-negative-film)

That may not help 100%, so after that, see if your scanning software has a dust removal feature.

If *that* doesn't get you 100% of the way there, then you are left with spot-touching the image - known as the "[Healing Tool/Brush" in Photoshop](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/retouching-repairing-images.html). Lightroom also has a Spot tool, and GIMP does as well though I'm not sure what they call it. It's an easy tool to learn for this use, though it will be tedious in application if you have a lot of photographs.